# How do i write in my txt file and append text below

Tags: c++, notepad

I cant seem to have output appears in my `.txt` file.
I would like to append below the text file in future.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string month;
    int year;
    stringstream filename;

    cin >> month;
    cin >> year;

    filename << "Expenses_" << month << "_" << year << ".txt";
    ofstream myfile(filename.str()); 

    myfile.open(filename.str());
    myfile << "Hello World!";
    myfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Any good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should have information about it. [A good reference of the C++ input/output system](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) should also be helpful.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/

Answer (score 0):

Open your file as:

```
std::ofstream myfile(filename.str(), std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
```

And passing the filename while creating the object of `ofstream` will open that file too, you don't need to call `.open` again.

Answer (score 0):

```
ofstream myfile(filename.str(), ofstream::out | ofstream::app);
```

The constructor automatically opens the file **for writing** and moves the writing pointer **to the end of the file**, so you can append to the file. There's no need to open the file again because the `std::ofstream(const char*, int)` consturctor **has already opened the file for you**.

The alternative is:

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open(filename.str(), ofstream::out | ofstream::app);
```